# RStudio does not load workspace when rprofile.site changes working directory

Tags: r, rstudio

We want R/RStudio to have its current directory in a specific folder. We make this happen with this in the rprofile.site:

```
setwd(Sys.getenv("RWORKSPACE"))
```

This works fine. But then RStudio does not automatically load the workspace left from last session. From the prompt I can `load(".RData")` just fine. RStudio loads the workspace just fine, if I let the working directory alone in `rprofile.site`.

Plain R (c:\program files....) **does** load the workspace also when the working directory is changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: In which environment are you working? windows, linux? I am astonished that the double `setwd` does not bug.

Comment: If you're not automating something, consider using projects. They set working directory to the `/` folder where .rproj is stationed.

Comment: Sorry, the double setwd is from my documentation. It failed in real life, but the docs remained bugged.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this manually, you could use Rstudio projects. It is the classic way to manage R session and specific folders.

Basically, it is like having a parallel session set up for your project, with it's own `.Rhistory` and `.Rdata` files.

[Here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects).

What you need to know:

- One project per project (my tautology class progress well, thank you)
- One folder per project
- go to file -> new project -> existing directory and select your folder
- when you quit, you could save your current session
- Your previous session will be loaded each time you work on your project
- With Rstudio projects, you have to open the `.Rproj` script of your project to be set up.

If needed, you could upgrade the .Rprofile by having a modified copy in the main folder for customisation of your set up.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code like this:

```
setwd(Sys.getenv("RWORKSPACE"))
if (file.exists(paste(getwd(),"/.RData",sep="")))
{
    load(paste(getwd(),"/.RData",sep=""))
    print (paste("[Workspace", paste(getwd(),"/.RData",sep=""), "loaded]"))
}
```

This works. I do not want users workspace files filling up their profile (this is on windows on a shared server). I am all for projects, but this takes care of casual tinkering.